# Remote Procedure Call slow returning error

Tags: vpn, dns, wmi

I have a server process that sends a WMI query to multiple PCs at frequent intervals. Normally it works fine and takes about 1 second to get a result from each PC. When there is a problem reaching a PC, for example: a user has taken the PC home and is using the VPN - the error return could take up to 60 seconds.

Is there some way to get WMI calls to **"fail fast"** and not hang my display process for random long intervals? I don't want to add 1 second to all of the requests by doing a Ping to each PC first. I am not asking for help on *why* the calls fail - I don't care why. I just want it to be evenly fast always.

I have searched extensively and there doesn't seem to be a test like "*is a user logged in to this PC*" which does not use WMI. Does such a thing exist or are all the eggs in the WMI / RPC basket?

I think the problem is that as PCs alternately connect directly at work (wired), then at home via VPN, the DNS records lag behind and the WMI call goes to a no longer valid IP. (I added a Ping test before the WMI call, which doesn't slow the process noticably, but avoids the hang if error.) Could this be the cause? Is there a way to modify the Connect Options to mean: "don't try very hard"? That seems like the solution, but I don't understand the very confusing options for both Connect, and Enumerate results. Is it due to a TCP level issue? Ping is just a UDP packet, so it fails immediately if no route. Any ideas for WMI calls?

Comment: To clarify: I would be willing to add the call for "is a user logged on" to get some useful information, if it is a fast call that doesn't hang on error, but I don't want to add just a bare Ping before each request.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks for the reply. It is an ASP.Net web page. I went with the preemptive Pings and it doesn't seem to slow it noticably, but avoids the hang from WMI error. I also came up with a trivial, no added time way to detect if the user is logged on or not.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Good luck! :)